# Почему данные не отправляются на сервер?

Tags: php, jquery

> Почему то данные не отправляются на сервер пишет пустую ошибку на     console.log(response); эту строку
>
> php

```
<?php 
    $username = trim(filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $email = trim(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
    $pass = trim(filter_var($_POST['pwd1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $pass_rep = trim(filter_var($_POST['pwd2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    if(strlen($username) <= 3)
        exit();
    else if(strlen($email) <= 3)
        exit();
    else if(strlen($pass) <= 3)
        exit();
    else if ($pass != $pass_rep)
        exit();
    $hash ="dsuiasodiasda";
    $pass = md5($pass . $hash);

    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'testing';
    $host = 'host';

    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(name, email, pass) VALUES(?, ?, ?)';
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute([$username, $email, $pass]);
?>








> jquery

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#regsub').click(function() {
        var name = $('#username').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var pass = $('#pwd1').val();
        var pass_rep = $('#pwd2').val();
    
        $.ajax({
        url: 'php/reg.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {'username': name, 'email' : email,'pwd1': pass,'pwd2': pass_rep},
        dataType: 'html',
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error:function(xhr,status,error){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: С чего Вы взяли что ничего не отправляется, каков статус запроса в вкладке Network? `эту строку` -- какую строку? В приведенном Вами PHP коде, Вы абсолютно ничего не возвращаете, потому `response` всегда будет пустым в Вашем случае. Опшите ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: строку response,а так данные в базу данных не отправляются почему то

Comment: Так не **отправляются**, не **принимаются** или не **записываются**? Сделайте так, чтобы РНР что-то выводил. Настройте в PDO режим информирования об ошибках, включите в РНР режим отображения ошибок и смотрите в инструментах не консоль, а вкладку Сеть.

Comment: не записываются

Comment: не записываются  потому что Undefined array key "username"  видимо))   который вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1541496