# Warning: Undefined array key "username" in C:\xampp\htdocs\sait\php\reg.php on line 6 ошибка?

Tags: php, jquery

> Почему возникает данная ошибка?
> php

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $username = trim(filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS));
    $email = trim(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
    $pass = trim(filter_var($_POST['pwd1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS));
    $pass_rep = trim(filter_var($_POST['pwd2'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS));
    
    if(strlen($username) <= 3)
        exit();
    else if(strlen($email) <= 3)
        exit();
    else if(strlen($pass) <= 3)
        exit();
    else if ($pass != $pass_rep)
        exit();

    $hash ="dsuiasodiasda";
    $pass = md5($pass . $hash);

    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'testing';
    $host = 'host';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(name, email, pass) VALUES(?, ?, ?)';
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute([$username, $email, $pass]);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ошибка соединения с базой данных: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
?>
```

> jquery

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#regsub').click(function() {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var pass = $('#pwd1').val();
    var pass_rep = $('#pwd2').val();

    $.ajax({
    url: 'php/reg.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {'username': name, 'email' : email,'pwd1': pass,'pwd2': pass_rep},
    dataType: 'html',
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error:function(xhr,status,error){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump()` или `print_r()` суперглобального массива `$_POST` и посмотрите что Вам приходит в POST запросе. Судя по ошибке, элемента массива с таким ключом не существует.

Comment: *"Почему возникает данная ошибка?"* --- в ошибке написано почему. Потому что ключа такого нет в массиве

Comment: всмысле нету ключа в массиве?

Comment: А у этого может быть несколько смыслов?

Comment: В форме отправки, где **button** с **id** `regsub`, есть **input** с **id** `username`? Например такой `<input type="text" id="username"/>`

Comment: @kham Покажи свой html. Я думаю знаю в чём проблема. Но нужно убедиться

Answer (score -2):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что в POST-заросе не передан параметр `username`. Ошибки не будет, если использовать `filter_input` вместо `filter_var` + `$_POST`, например вот так:

```
$username = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS));
$email = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
...
```

Comment: Вы это серьёзно сейчас? "Если воткнуть голову в песок, то хищник меня не увидит, и не съест"? Если не будет ошибки, то это сразу решит проблему передачи значения из формы?

Comment: @Ипатьев Вопрос был почему возникает ошибка, по моему я на него ответил. Есть там форма или нет и каким способом был отправлен запрос мы не знаем.

Comment: Если бы запрос был сделан приведенным javascript-кодом то ошибки бы не было, скорее всего автор вызвал свой скрипт php/reg.php напрямую в браузере и увидел ошибку, в данном случае моя рекомендация позволит избежать этих ворнингов.

Comment: "избежать ворнингов " позволит проверка на отправку формы. при том что вопрос вообще не про "избежать".

Comment: @Ипатьев Какая форма? Про форму в вопросе нет ни слова. По твоему нормально, если при вызове скрипта на странице ворнинги сыпятся? А они будут, если в запросе по какой-то причине не будет соответствующего параметра.

Comment: Попробуйте читать комментарии, перед тем как отвечать на них. Чтобы не сыпались ворнинги, надо сделать проверку на отправку формы. Если вы не понимаете, откуда тут форма, это говорит только о том, что вы не умеете читать код. И даже не понимаете, что делает ваш собственный. попробуйте еще раз посмотреть на то, что сами же написали в своем ответе. И подумайте, при чем тут форма :)

Comment: Забавно, видимо вы думаете, что форма - это единственный способ отправить POST-запрос :)
Меня распирает любопытство, какую "проверку отправки формы" вы предлагаете, что-то типа !empty($_POST)?

Comment: Любую, на ваш вкус. Я вижу, вы полагаете себя гуру веб-программирования. Это мешает вам понять собственные ошибки, очевидные всем окружающим. Попробуйте все-таки отбросить спесь, и понять вопрос, который был задан. Собственно, тут и вопрос-то дурацкий, под удаление, и совершенно не стоит ответа. Но если уж отвечать на него, то разобравшись, а не предлагая ненужный костыль.

Comment: Вы точно не гуру в веб-программировании :) Ошибка очевидная всем окружающим - это то, что нет никакой проверки на отправку формы. Единственный способ в данном случае избежать ворнингов это не получать значение прямым обращением к $_POST, без предварительной проверки, типа isset, либо тем способом, который я предложил.

Comment: :))) Как многие начинающие, вы путаете ошибки и сообщения о них. И вместо того, чтобы исправлять ошибку, пытаетесь бороться с сообщениями :) Программист не должен "избегать ворнингов". Программист должен писать код так, чтобы их не было. То есть, избегать надо ошибок. А вот сообщений об ошибках избегать не надо. Они придуманы как раз для того чтобы помочь программисту исправить ошибку. Вот как в данном случае у автора вопроса. Вы же предлагаете вести себя как тот самый страус - задавить сообщения об ошибках. Но код от этого рабочим не станет, вот в чем проблема.

Comment: Вы этот бред в чат GPT генерируете или у вас в голове такое?

Comment: Чем агрессивнее вы общаетесь, тем глупее выглядите :) Единственный смысл вашего кода - это "избежать" *сообщений* об ошибках. Не ошибок, а сообщений об ошибках. Подумайте об этом. А мне больше нечего добавить к нашей дискуссии, которую вы со временем обязательно найдете очень познавательной.